# android pass parameter into onclick event

Tags: android, android-intent

In the following code how to pass pwd into onclick event

```
String pwd ="/root";   

final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {   
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng)
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,pwd , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

EDIT 1:

```
final String pwd = null;

string pwd ="root"; //Error remove final keyword
final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {   
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng)
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,pwd , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Can u give me an example.pwd is global

Comment: Please look at public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) if i add onclick definition changes

Comment: @MAC : Yes declaring it global solved the issue for me of the examples here..Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare pwd as Globle as per MAC suggestion solved the problem @MAC

Answer (score 0):

declare your String pwd above the onCreate method.

```
class demo extends Activity
{String pwd;
onCreate()
{pwd="/root";
final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {   
public void onClick(View arg0) {
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,pwd , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I have did it once

```
public class NatigationOnClick implements OnClickListener {

    String title;
    String html;
    private QuickActionWeb webQuickAction;
    private Context context;
    private View row;

    public NatigationOnClick(String title, String html, Context context,
            View row) {
        this.title = title;
        this.html = html;
        this.context = context;
        this.row = row;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        webQuickAction = new QuickActionWeb(context, QuickActionWeb.VERTICAL,
                title + "<br/>" + html);
        webQuickAction.show(row);

    }

}
```

now...

```
view.setOnClickListener(new NatigationOnClick(title, html, context, row));
```

Hope that help

Comment: public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng)

Comment: I have did this for onclick you can refer to the same way by implementing OnItemClick

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you:

```
final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getPwd(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});


String pwd = "root";

private String getPwd()
{
    return pwd;
}
```